# GeoPoint does not allowed to be stored in Room

Tags: android, location, google-cloud-firestore, android-room, geopoints

Edited: Tested as suggested by Nazariy Moshenskiy's answer

I tried storing [GeoPoints](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint) object in android's abstraction data persistence layer [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). Seems like this operation is not allowed.

Project does not compile with following error:

> error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
>   consider adding a type converter for it.

Are there any solutions to achieve this? (compatible TypeConverter)

PS: I do not want to change my model class' object type to long, long or any other type as I am using GeoPoints within my model class to store in Firestore and retrieve based on parameters we can provide to the query against the GeoPoints.

Comment: My friend, you should try before asking.....

Comment: Tested, no luck :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the OPs solution did not work I decided to implement a TypeConverter to achieve this. Even though the question has lot of downvotes thinking this can't be achieved out of the box, I will share my solution for whoever actually tried and failed to achieve this.

So I wrote a class called CustomTypeConverters and annotated two methods with @TypeConverter.

1. stringToGeoPoint(String data)

> This method will take a JSON String as the input parameter. Then it
> will create a GeoPoint object using Gson library with the
> representation of GeoPoint.class and return it.

2. geoPointToString(GeoPoint geoPoint)

> This method will take a GeoPoint object as the input parameter. Then
> it will create a JSON String object using Gson library and return it.

**CustomTypeConverters.java**

```
public class CustomTypeConverters {

    @TypeConverter
    public static GeoPoint stringToGeoPoint(String data) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(data, GeoPoint.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String geoPointToString(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        return new Gson().toJson(geoPoint);
    }

}
```

Then we need to point this converter using annotations within GeoPoint object we defined in our POJO. Assume I have a User class with a GeoPoint object,

```
@TypeConverters(CustomTypeConverters.class)
private GeoPoint geoPoint;
```

I verified the answer by browsing, data/data/your-application-package/databases in the device I am running this code.

Answer (score 0):

What @channae said is true but there is something missing :
You also need to add your converter in the db file like this :

```
@Database(entities = [Wine::class,Store::class], version = 3)
@TypeConverters(GeoPointConverter::class)
abstract class WineryDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
 ....
}
```